# PCA analysis using python scikit-learn - type error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to replicate the PCA example found [here](http://python-for-multivariate-analysis.readthedocs.io/a_little_book_of_python_for_multivariate_analysis.html) but when trying to run the pca_summary() I get the following error, any thoughts much appreciated. Thanks!

```
   raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.0

Comment: i can reproduce the error using python 3.6. it seems that this line: summary = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b, c), index=names, columns=columns) that is inside pca_summary function causes the problem in python 3.6.

Comment: that's because `zip` returns a list on python 2.7, but a generator on python 3.6. change it to list(zip(a,b,c)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem caused by `zip`.

This is because `zip` changed in python 3 and it returns an iterator now.

[see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121009/python-3-zip-is-an-iterator-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

In the `pca_summary` function do this:

```
def pca_summary(pca, standardised_data, out=True):
    names = ["PC"+str(i) for i in range(1, len(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)+1)]
    a = list(np.std(pca.transform(standardised_data), axis=0))
    b = list(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
    c = [np.sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_[:i]) for i in range(1, len(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)+1)]
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("sdev", "Standard deviation"), ("varprop", "Proportion of Variance"), ("cumprop", "Cumulative Proportion")])
    summary = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b, c)), index=names, columns=columns)
    if out:
        print("Importance of components:")
        display(summary)
    return summary
```

So just replace

```
summary = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b, c), index=names, columns=columns)
```

with

```
summary = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b, c)), index=names, columns=columns)
```